# AzureDataLake-Gen2 with JavaSdk and Proxy

Tags: java, maven, proxy, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a Relatively simple objective:

Upgrade a software accessing ADLS-Gen1 (using maven package: https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java), which is pretty straight forward to use. The application uses service principals for authentication and a simple http-proxy.

Snippet of pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-data-lake-store-sdk</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.5</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Example class for accessing ADLS-Gen1

```
public class AdlsService {

  // ... Some initialisation for AUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, CLIENT_KEY, CLIENT_ID and ACCOUNT_FQDN

  private ADLStoreClient buildClient() throws IOException {
    AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new ClientCredsTokenProvider(AUTH_TOKEN_ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_KEY);
    return ADLStoreClient.createClient(ACCOUNT_FQDN, accessTokenProvider);
  }

  public boolean checkExists(final String filePath) throws IOException {
    ADLStoreClient adlStoreClient = buildClient();
    return adlStoreClient.checkExists(filePath);
  }
}
```

The new version should access ADLS-Gen2 using the officially recommended Maven package (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-datalake).

Snippet of pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-file-datalake</artifactId>
    <version>12.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Several things are not working out quite as smoothly as initially intended: Numerous dependencies are implicitly required and not documented anywhere, the Proxy configuration is not doing what it should and, as I am ferly new to Netty, I'm having a hard time configuring it all as I want it.

---

**Hence the question:** If I have a simple application, that reads files from ADLS-Gen1 through a HTTP proxy. What are the necessary steps to make it work with ADLS-GEN2 and what are my debugging options to make help me find issues and misconfigurations.

Documentations for this is spread out and does not mention everything that is required. (Proof for that is that after 1-2 days I'm still working on making the connection work at all)

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, you have an HTTP proxy server. You want to access Azure data lake gen2 through the proxy server. If so, please refer to the following code

```
String accountName = "";
String accountKey = "";
StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
String endpoint = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.dfs.core.windows.net", accountName);
ProxyOptions proxyOptions = new new ProxyOptions(ProxyOptions.Type.HTTP,
                    new InetSocketAddress("proxyURL", "proxyPort"))
                    .setCredentials("proxyUsername", "proxyPassword");
HttpClient httpClient = new NettyAsyncHttpClientBuilder()
            .proxy(proxyOptions).build();
DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = builder.credential(clientSecretCredential)
            .endpoint(endpoint).httpClient(httpClient).buildClient();
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/wiki/HTTP-clients#configuring-http-clients).